# Tecla enter não dar submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Como fazer com que a tecla enter não dê *submit* em um formulário?

Exemplo: em um input apertando o *enter* nada acontecer.

Hoje se aperto o *enter*, o navegador dá um *submit*, comos e tivesse clicado no botão enviar.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Você pode substituir o handler para o comportamento padrão:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Ou, na tag Form:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter)

Comment: Ah, o cara foi mais rápido ;)

Comment: Leeevemente @WallaceMaxters ;)

Answer (score 8):

Assim também dá:

```
 $('#form').bind('submit', false);

 $('button#submit').click(function()
 {
    $('#form').submit();
 });
```

Isso fará que o formulário só seja enviado quando clicar no botão de submit.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `event.preventDefault();`

Isso impedirá que o evento padrão ocorra.

O uso de `return false` dentro de um manipulador de eventos jQuery é efetivamente o mesmo que chamar `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Veja esta pergunta para uma melhor explicação: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 1):

Alternativa com JavaScript puro:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        
    e.preventDefault();
    
  }

});
```

Na primeira linha estamos adicionando um evento de **keydown** ao documento

Ou seja, sempre que for apertada uma tecla, teremos um evento sendo disparado no DOM

Depois verificamos se a tecla apertada é o enter, que tem o código de 13, com a comparação de **keyCode**

Caso seja enter, impedimos o evento default com **preventDefault**, que é o envio do formulário ao servidor